# Cannot fire itemcommand event asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to populate a datalist control onchange of a dropdown list. I am unable to fire Itemcommand event of datalist. When I populate datalist on page_load event it works fine. but I don't know what is happening with the dropdown.

code behind:

```
 protected void dlSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CategoryID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();

        using (TestEntities db = new TestEntities())
        {
            IEnumerable<Test.Product> Test= //linq expression here
            dlProducts.DataSource = Test;
            dlProducts.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you want to bind a datalist with dropdown selection then must try for dropdown `selectedIndexChanged` event,why you want to use `Item Command`

Comment: check this link as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716578/itemcommand-event-not-firing-for-datalist

Comment: datalist is binding on change of dropdown but after binding i cannot fire itemcommand event of datalist.

Comment: are u using `Page.IsPostBack` property on `Page_Load`,if not then use it and check my answer as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using event handler.

```
dlProducts.ItemCommand += new DataListCommandEventHandler(dlProducts_ItemCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack) //this IF statement is what prevents re-binding on PostBack 
    { 
        // Code to bind datalist..
    } 

}
```

*Note :-*
 You must not databind on post back. Otherwise any pending event handler requests are cancelled.

Comment: i am not binding datalist on load. i am binding it change of dropdown values.

Answer (score 0):

You are fire Itemcommand of datalist by dropdownlist. You see in my video is uploaded on youtube link given below :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnZp6y2n_h8

In this video I am using "ID" variable. This variable just like a ItemIndex. This Id provide dropdownlist changed Datalistitem index.

It is like a (e.ItemIndex=Id) you are use ID on e.ItemIndex place .